# Folder redirection APPDATA permission server 2012 r2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, folder-redirection

I have setup Folder redirection in a terminal server environment.

I am using a bat file to set permission for the users.

```
icacls d:\users\%user% /grant:r "%user%":(OI)(CI)F
```

however using the above code also gives user right to view the contents of the app-data folder which i want to restrict.

i tried by denying list contents permissions to the users  but applications in the app-data fails to execute.

exact problem http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Q_27718074.html

even no solution there

Answer (score 0):

1. It's the user's folder. Why do you want to restrict it?
2. If you have the Share and NTFS permissions set correctly on the parent folder then Windows will set the correct permissions upon redirection of the folder. Manual intervention isn't required.
3. If you need administrative access to the redirected folders then uncheck the `Grant the user exclusive rights...` check box on the Settings tab of the redirected folder properties in the GPO.

Comment: there are some applications in app-data folder for which i want to restrict user to view it. If i grant full contol using windows security tab, it works has intended but if use icacls, permissions gets messed up someway